# An extension of von Neumann entropy to observables

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, observables, quantum-states

Suppose we define the "[entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy)" of a [self-adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint) matrix $\rho$ as the real number $S(\rho)$ given by:

$$S(\rho)=-\text{tr}(\rho\log|\rho|)$$

(notice the absolute value on $\rho$, as $\rho$ may have negative eigenvalues). While clearly such an entropy function can be negative (e.g. $S\left(-\frac{1}{n}I_n\right)<0$), I would like to know if such an entropy function is necessarily positive (i.e., non-negative) on [bipartite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bipartite) self-adjoint matrices whose marginals are density matrices (states). More precisely, if $\rho_{AB}\in A\otimes B$ is a self-adjoint matrix such that $\rho_A=\text{tr}_B(\rho_{AB})$ and $\rho_B=\text{tr}_A(\rho_{AB})$ are both density matrices, is it necessarily the case that $S(\rho_{AB})\geq 0$?

Comment: What is an absolute value of a matrix?

Comment: Its defined in terms of functional calculus.

Comment: @Roger perhaps you mean differentiable AT zero? In any case, what does this have to do with the question? The function $f(x)=x\log|x|$ has a well-defined limit as $x\to 0$, and this is all that is needed.

Comment: Hi Norbert Schuch: It seems the [tag:counterexamples] tag is prone to become a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Also imagine the work to implement this tag consistently for all questions.

Comment: @Qmechanic Conceded. I did not edit to add that tag (but to fix the minus sign) -- the tag was just a spontaneous decision when thinking about tags. I *do* think it would be a very helpful tag for someone having some claim about X and wanting to know if it is correct. So from the point of view of finding questions, I think it makes a lot of sense (e.g., you could search [quantum-information][counterexamples], which would be much more specific for questions aimed at debunking a conjecture). But I agree it is a meta-tag. (I just wouldn't say meta-tags are bad, as long as they help to ...

Comment: ... filter questions.) Implementing it consistently for all questions (retroactively) would be indeed a mess, potentially, but this is true for pretty much any tag which is newly introduced. -- Anyway, I think it would be quite useful and do no harm, but I won't start an argument over it.

Comment: ... In that sense, I think it is a much better tag than [homework], as it helps to *find* questions one might be looking for, whereas [homework] I guess mostly helps people to *avoid* questions. (Though that is a good use of tags, too.)

Comment: I think $x\log|x|$ is still problematic at zero.

Comment: @RogerVadim But this 'problem' you have for the classical Shannon entropy, too.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker for classical Shannon entropy one does not need to cross zero. Anyhow, as I stated previously, it has to be properly defined in the question: for now you, the OP author and the other guy are pursuing three different explanations.

Comment: @Roger For classical Shannon entropy you don’t need to cross zero, but you do need to take a one-sided limit approaching zero from the right, and this limit is zero. And it also turns out that the limit of $-x\log|x|$ is zero when approaching zero from the left as well. So this clears up any issues about crossing zero.

Comment: @dezign I am not sure which of the three definitions you are talking about now: Norbert Schuh above spoke about Taylor expansion, and it remains problematic at zero.

Comment: @Roger If you do a power series expansion $f(M)=\sum c_n M^n$, you can diagonalize the $M=ADA^{-1}$ and pull out $M$, so f(M)= A(\sum c_n D^n)A^{-1}$ = A f(D) A^{-1}$, with the natural convention that for a diagonal matrix, $f(D)$ acts componentwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\rho=p\lvert a\rangle\langle a\rvert+(1-p)\lvert b\rangle\langle b\rvert$ , with $\lvert a\rangle$ and $\lvert b\rangle$ two orthogonal maximally entanged states.

Then, the reduced density matrices of $\rho$ are maximally mixed states, and thus valid density matrices, independent of the value of $p$.

On the other hand, $S(\rho) = -p\log|p|-(1-p)\log|1-p|$ is negative for all $p\notin[0;1]$.

Comment: Note that $\rho$ in this example is not positive semi-definite, which a density operator usually should be. So I'd be careful talking about "reduced density matrices". But the requirements of the question seem to be met.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess this is just meant to mean "partial trace", with a physics connotation. Note that the partial trace is the unique linear extension of the reduced density matrix defined for positive operators.